# Anaconda: not creating environment.yml file

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm using `conda env export` to create an environment.yml file as [the documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment) suggest. Although the .yml file content displays on the Anaconda Prompt, it doesn't seems to create any file (neither on current or any directory).

Where could the file be stored? / Why it doesn't create a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redirect the output to a file. See [this page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment) for more details.

You're looking for `conda env export > name-your-env-file-here.yml`.

Comment: How stupid of me! I thought `> environment.yml` was the output, not part of the command. Thank you for your answer.